# Replace index in list

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list containing n identical 3x3 matrices, where n is the number of zeros in one such matrix.

In my first matrix, I want to replace the first 0 with the integer 2.
In the second matrix, I want to replace the second 0 with 2.
This goes on until the n:th matrix where I want to replace the n:th 0 with 2. I.e. every matrix should have only one index replaced.

My code so far:

```
def replaceZero(x):

    # Omitted code where I count number of 0 in x
    n = 9 # in this example

    # Creating a list which holds n matrices
    lists = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        lists.append(x)

    # Replacing the i:th 0 with 2
    for i in range(0,n):
        m = -1
        for j in range(0,3):
            for k in range(0,3):
                if lists[i][j][k] == 0:
                    m = m + 1
                    if m == i:
                        lists[i][j][k] = 2

    return lists

# Example of a matrix
x = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Although, too many zeros are replaced and the replacement is identical for each matrix.

I am trying to increment `m` with 1 each time a zero is found. Only when `m` has the same value as the index of the current matrix should the replacement occur.

Comment: Please provide details as to how "it doesn't work": what did you expect, and what did you get instead.  (Showing how you call your function would be a good idea, too.)

Comment: is it guaranteed to have n zeroes?

Comment: No, eventually the argument will have no zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you build your list using nine references to **x**.  You don't have nine *copies* of **x**; you have nine references to the *same* **x**.  If you change one, you change them all.

Instead, alter with this technique:

```
import copy
...
    lists.append(copy.deepcopy(x))
```

The full documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).  Since you have a multi-level structure, you need to use **deepcopy**; if you use just **copy**, you'll get nine matrices that point to the *same* three vectors of zeros.

Does this get you moving?

---

Glad to be of help.  You can also simplify the inner loops:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    j = i / 3
    k = i % 3
    lists[i][j][k] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to append the matrix using copy by value not by reference. This can be done using `copy.deepcopy` as:

```
import copy
```

and replace:

```
lists.append(x)
```

with

```
lists.append(copy.deepcopy(x))
```